# How to get reputation credit for migrated questions?

Tags: discussion, search

I asked 2 questions ([here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149570/why-doesnt-this-search-work-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149571/how-to-find-out-how-long-ago-someone-checked-out-document-in-sharepoint-foundati)) that were migrated to sharepoint.stackexchange from superuser at my request, which is great. However, I am having a cascading problem: I don't appear as the person who asked them, so my reputation is still 1, which means I can't comment on people's answers (need reputation of 15) to get clarifications that will help me accept one. Since I don't appear as the person who asked the questions, I can't accept answers and gain reputation that way. And regrettably I don't know enough about SharePoint to answer questions and gain reputation - I am here to learn.

How can I get reputation for questions that I asked elsewhere and were migrated here? I just want to be able to manage my questions (make comments, accept answers), not seeking glory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [contact us](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form below to contact the StackExchange folks to have your accounts merged. Moderators cannot do that.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed to do.